# What is a noun for "one who is adroit"?

Tags: nouns

I'm looking for a noun meaning "one who is adroit" or "one who is clever/skillful".  Can I use the word "adroit" as a noun?  All my googling has only turned up the noun-form "adroitness", which is clearly not what I'm after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Adept* can be used as a noun meaning *exceptionally skilled at one thing or many things in general*. It's a bit archaic to use it as a noun, but I suppose *adroit* isn't all that common a word, either. :)

Comment: This is the closest I've seen so far to what I'm looking for.  Maybe the exact word doesn't exist, but this is good enough that I'll accept it.  Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

You could say that one who is *adroit* is a *[virtuoso](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/virtuoso)*.

Comment: Oh man, that's so close.  I'm not sure I want the artistic implication, but otherwise this would be perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Considering [all the synonyms](https://www.google.com/search?q=adroit&oq=adroit) listed in Google's results:

> skillful, adept, dexterous, deft, nimble, able, capable, skilled, expert, masterly, masterful, master, practiced, handy, polished, slick, proficient, accomplished, gifted, talented

*master* or *expert* seem to be among reasonable options.

Comment: I did actually do this very search myself and wasn't happy with the results.  I was hoping for something that perhaps does not exist.

Comment: I don't know if I understand your quest for something that does not exist. If you're the only one who understands your question, it's by definition not relevant to anyone else.

Comment: I don't think that I am the only one who understands, since there's a pretty good answer in the comments above.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen *adroit* used as a noun that way.  Consider using *expert* as an alternative.